# finding percentiles with standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation

This is a question on my worksheet that I'm not sure how to start:

If you know that the mean salary for your profession is $\$45000$ with a standard deviation of $\$2000$, to what percentile does your salary of $\$41240$ correspond?

Answer (score 0):

How many standard deviations below the mean is $41200?$  Now look up in a z-score table what percentage of the area is below that.  You are making the assumption (which is expected, but badly wrong) that salaries are normally distributed.

Comment: Thanks! I honestly didn't realize it was one of those problems where it corresponded with the table.This helped a lot thanks.